# How to install Django app on a customers server without exposing the business logic and db access

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a simple data mining web application using Django Rest Framework + some simple javascript on client side and I want to offer it as a paid service in future. The problem is, that the application will be processing sensitive and some times huge data with restricted access. So my initial idea is to treat this kind of cases by installing the simpler version of the website on the customers server in his intranet (only localhost) and all the data handling could be done on his machine, so there would be no need to set up special permissions to access his data from my website and also I would not have the need to host all the data.

The database for the administration of this local server should be of course on my server, so I could easily change the content and functionality through the db.

Now the problem is, that I would like to do all this without exposing the business logic of my application. The main data handling functions would be done in cython, so the customer would only see the compiled code. But how to hide my master database for user administration, logging and everything sensitive from the customer, if the application on his server needs to have access to these data?

Comment: Hm, basic design question is if the customer will give you access to his machines/intranet. Maybe you should implement your Application as a webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are Database Views.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx